# Transpose the dataframe obtained from json from each row

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I have a dataframe called df:

```
ID    Message
1     {"user":user10, "message":{"sender":"k3532", "card":87876}}
2     {"user":user14, "message":{"sender":"hg769", "card":6434363654}}
3     {"user":user22, "message":{"sender":"gjhyj5", "card":87676876, "allowed":true}}
```

I do this to turn json into dataframe:

```
message1 <- df[1,]$Message %>% 
  fromJSON() 
data_raw1 <- enframe(unlist(message1))
```

I get dataframe data_raw1 from json from first row, which looks like this:

```
name              value
user              user10
message.sender    k3532
message.card      87876
```

Now, I want to trnaspose it and bind it with original dataframe in this way. So, after transposing it must look like this:

```
name    user       message.sender   message.card
value   user10       k3532            87876
```

And i want to do that with each json in each row and then bind them with original datafarme. So the final result must look like this:

```
ID    name    user       message.sender   message.card    message.allowed
1     value   user10       k3532            87876            NA
2     value   user14       hg769            6434363654       NA
3     value   user22       gjhyj5           87676876         TRUE
```

How could i do that? This kind of transformation is way too complicated for my level. Its necessary, that it happens with that transposing operation

Comment: french_fries, any updates? You seem to have had problems with the code, but I think the problems are inconsistent with the data.

Answer (score 2):

Much simpler.

First, I'll fix the data, since it's not valid json with unquoted names (`user10` versus `"user10"`):

```r
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:3,
  Message = c(
    '{"user":"user10", "message":{"sender":"k3532", "card":87876}}',
    '{"user":"user14", "message":{"sender":"hg769", "card":6434363654}}',
    '{"user":"user22", "message":{"sender":"gjhyj5", "card":87676876, "allowed":true}}'
  )
)
```

Now:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  bind_cols(., do.call(data.frame, jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(.$Message)))) %>%
  select(-Message)
#  Imported 3 records. Simplifying...
#   ID   user message.sender message.card message.allowed
# 1  1 user10          k3532        87876              NA
# 2  2 user14          hg769   6434363654              NA
# 3  3 user22         gjhyj5     87676876            TRUE
```

(perhaps more pipe-like/friendly?)

```r
jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(df$Message)) %>%
  do.call(data.frame, .) %>%
  bind_cols(select(df, ID), .)
```

or in base R:

```r
cbind(
  ID = df$ID,
  do.call(data.frame, jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(df$Message)))
)
```

---

**Edited** to add `do.call(data.frame, ...)`, thanks to @27ϕ9 for the suggestion. Without it, it was actually nested:

```r
df %>%
  bind_cols(., do.call(data.frame, jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(.$Message)))) %>%
  select(-Message) %>%
  str
#  Imported 3 records. Simplifying...
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ ID             : int  1 2 3
#  $ user           : chr  "user10" "user14" "user22"
#  $ message.sender : chr  "k3532" "hg769" "gjhyj5"
#  $ message.card   : num  8.79e+04 6.43e+09 8.77e+07
#  $ message.allowed: logi  NA NA TRUE
df %>%
  bind_cols(., jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(.$Message))) %>%
  select(-Message) %>%
  str
#  Imported 3 records. Simplifying...
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ ID     : int  1 2 3
#  $ user   : chr  "user10" "user14" "user22"
#  $ message:'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ sender : chr  "k3532" "hg769" "gjhyj5"
#   ..$ card   : num  8.79e+04 6.43e+09 8.77e+07
#   ..$ allowed: logi  NA NA TRUE
```

And if `is.factor(df$Message)` is true, then you need to either

1. `df$Message <- as.character(df$Message)` first; or
2. use `textConnection(as.character(df$Message))` internally, since `factor`s are not recognized by `textConnection`.

Comment: it says Error in textConnection(df$Message) : invalid 'text' argument

Comment: `factor`s? Try `jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(as.character(df$Message)))`

Comment: i don't get.  this code ```df %>%
  bind_cols(., do.call(data.frame, jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(.$Message)))) %>%
  select(-Message) %>%
  str``` still gives the same error

Comment: It doesn't for me, so your data is different. Please provide the output using `dput`, as it is unambiguous.

Comment: Are you saying that this code doesn't work with my data, or it doesn't work with your data? If it doesn't work with my data, then we need to talk package versions to find out what is different. If it does work with mine but not with yours, then you still need to provide an unambiguous sample of your data, or at least explain clearly how my data is different. It might be informative to run `str(...)` on both yours and mine to see differences.